# How to make sure /etc/network/interfaces will bring the interface up?

Tags: networking, configuration

I have a headless box based on Debian. It is intended to be accessed via its network interface.
The Network is configured via the `/etc/network/interfaces`.
I'm trying to validate if the file is really valid. My idea is to check if the file have any error, and in this case, fallback to a default file.

My question is about the first part of the problem: detecting a error in the `interfaces` file.

I found a lot of questions about using `ifup --no-act` commands, but what I see in practice is that this method is not robust enough for my case. Take the following example:

```
root@arm:~# ifup --no-act --interfaces=/etc/network/interfaces eth0
run-parts  /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
ip addr add 1s23.123.123.123/255.255.255.192 broadcast +          dev eth0 label eth0
ip link set dev eth0   up
 ip route add default via 123.123.123.122  dev eth0
run-parts  /etc/network/if-up.d
```

Note the invalid IP address set (extra 's' in first octet). The command gives no error (that I can see, anyway) and if I reboot the machine with the file in this state, I would loose the networking capability. A valid `interfaces` gives me a very similar result (except for the `broadcast +` part):

```
root@arm:~# ifup --no-act --interfaces=/etc/network/interfaces eth0
run-parts  /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
ip addr add 123.123.123.123/255.255.255.192 broadcast 123.123.123.127     dev eth0 label eth0
ip link set dev eth0   up
 ip route add default via 123.123.123.122  dev eth0
run-parts  /etc/network/if-up.d
```

This is mainly the problem I'm trying to avoid. My question is how can I detect invalid configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` file? Does the plus sign indicates there's a error? What does it means? What is the best approach to solve this?

Comment: It is a difficult battle. Why not let the system/user decide? I remember a iptables frontend which lets "try" new rules; you apply a new configuration, and if the user does not reply in 30s that all is ok, it reverts to the old configuration.

Comment: What if you make a typo in the IP address and configure an address that's not routed to the machine? (say, you write `12.123...` instead of `123.123...`) There's no way `ifup` or anything else on the machine can know everything that could be wrong about the configuration. But do you really need this? How often do you make changes to the network configuration anyway?

Comment: @ilkkachu But that is a valid IP address. The user can still configure his/her PC IP accordingly and reach the box and fix that, [even if the address is unknown](https://superuser.com/a/309368/306138). In the example I posted, it seems the interface doesn't even go up, and the above wireshark method does not work (I tested it my self).

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro the problem is exactly the user. We haven't (yet) a good interface for the user enter a configuration, so the user have to edit the file manually. The problem is that lots of users are making mistakes that are rendering the boxes connectionless. Then, they have to send them back so I can fix the configuration over a serial prompt (which is/can not be accessible to the user). My goal is to prevent a config that would prevent the iface to go up in the first place.

Comment: @ricardomenzer, well, sure, if you're in the same L2 network, you can probably find out the IP address, and choose your own accordingly to connect. But that doesn't work if the network in between requires routing, or if someone messes the firewall configuration so that SSH doesn't go through, or disables the SSH server or... So the issue is centered on the user, if they have administrator access, they should know to not break things, or at least know how to fix them afterwards.

Comment: Yes. I know there's a lot of bad practices going on here. The user will have access to the box directly (same network). The problem is that, even the master hero of admins is prone to mistakes, and in this case it does not matter how educated he/she is, the problem will be the same. I'm trying to mitigate *this specific kind of error*, where the box's network is disabled due to a invalid IP configuration (in the sense of the configuration not being a IP address at all).

Comment: Why not giving them static IP addresses via DHCP, and preventing them editing network configs in the first place?

Comment: I don't have a DHCP server. The solution must be enclosed only in the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Call `ifup --no-act` with the network config to test and check the return code.

Long answer: I've been doing something very similar for an embedded appliance; here's the relevant part of the init script I created for this purpose, which is executed before `networking` is started, so it is ensured the system has a working ethernet setup.

```
ETH0_CUSTOM=/var/myproject/etc/interfaces.eth0 
result=1

if [ -f "${ETH0_CUSTOM}" ]; then
    ifup -n -i "${ETH0_CUSTOM}" eth0
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        ln -sf "${ETH0_CUSTOM}" /etc/network/interfaces.eth0
        result=0
    else
        echo "Validating ${ETH0_CUSTOM} failed"
    fi
fi

if [ ${result} -ne 0 ]; then
    ln -sf /etc/network/interfaces.eth0.default /etc/network/interfaces.eth0
fi
```

In the original `/etc/network/interfaces` the valid settings are included with

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.eth0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I see two issues/approaches here:

- protecting users from making mistakes; and
- having a way to test a modified configuration before making it permanent

For the first one, making all configuration through some smart-ish tool that makes more sanity checks than `$EDITOR /etc/foobar`. In this case, it could check that the IP address is valid, and that the default route is in the same network, etc. The tool could be some script, or a graphical/web-based administration interface (like you have on OpenWRT etc.)

The other thing would be to have the user verify the network configuration after it's in effect, the same way many systems have the user verify the display settings (resolution etc) and fall back to the last working configuration if the user does nothing.

So, something like this:

- Have a bootup configuration separate from the new configuration, allow the user to make changes to the *new* configuration only (not the bootup config!).
- When the user wants to apply the new configuration, schedule a reboot to happen in 5 minutes or so (`shutdown -r +5`), and then load the new configuration.
- Now, have the user check that they still access the system (including opening new SSH sessions).
- If they can, they can acknowledge the change, cancelling the reboot and copying the new configuration to the bootup configuration.
- If they can't access the system after the modifications are in effect, they can't verify the changes, and the restart will let them start over (provided the bootup configuration was fine, which it should be, since the system previously started using it.)

The idea should be applicable to changes in the network interface configuration, firewall configuration etc. But it does require that configuration is self-contained, so that you can't end in a situation where the new configuration only works because the previously effective bootup configuration contained some important rule)

(And of course, it's not absolutely necessary to actually reboot the system, just reset the configuration.)

---

None of this prevents root users from shooting themselves in the leg, of course, but at least you could provide some tool with a safety switch.

Having backup access through the console/serial port or such would still be best.

---

In this particular case, if your users are customed to editing `/etc/network/interfaces` and running `ifup`, you'd have to teach them out of it, which might be hard. Or you could change the system so that the actual configuration is really somewhere else, so they don't let old habits cause issues.

Comment: I made something similar: There's a boot script that checks if the interface is "UP" `grep`ping the `ifconfig` command. If not, a default `/etc/network/interfaces` is copied and `ifup` brings the interface up with the default configuration.